# How to change password in Angular with api?

Tags: html, angular, change-password

I want to add functionality of changing password of angular ts. In my component i am calling function of changing password from submit button. But this always show me unsuccessfull. It does not update password. I dont know what is the problem . Please help me how can i update my password. Any help will be appreciated Thankyou. …

[POST Update Password image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixhvs.jpg)

[use the api to updated from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1bbk.jpg)

## update.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UpdateService {
readonly rootUrl = 'https://qa.wtpspd.com';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
userAuthentication(userId, password) {
var accessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1ODI1NjAxOTYsImlhdCI6MTU4MjQ3Mzc5NiwiYWNjb3VudFR5cGUiOiJERUFMRVIiLCJ1c2VyRW1haWwiOiJzZWVkc0B0ZXN0Lm9yZyIsInVzZXJJZCI6MiwidXNlclJvbGUiOiJTRUxMRVIiLCJjb21wYW55SWQiOjF9.S2DYURk2vvu7533lvwTniFxF_xAjTOm4aG9hnVanOPU";
var bearerToken = "Bearer " + accessToken;
let data = {query: 'mutation($in: DealerUpdate!){updateDealer(in: $in){id}}', variables: { in : {
id: userId,
password: password
}},}
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': bearerToken,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}); 
let options = {
headers: httpHeaders
}; return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/graphql', data,{ headers:httpHeaders });
}}
```

## update.component.ts

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpdateService } from './update.service';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgotpwd',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdatedComponent implements OnInit {
  userId:string;
  isLoginError : boolean = false;
  password:string;
 constructor(private resetService:UpdateService,private router : Router) { }
 
 ngOnInit( ) {
  }
   OnSubmit(userId, password){
   this.resetService.userAuthentication(userId, password).subscribe((data : any)=>{
    console.log(data);
      localStorage.setItem('userToken',data.access_token);
       this.router.navigate(['/otp']);
     },
     (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
      this.isLoginError = true;
     });    
    }
}
```

## update.component.html

```html
    <div class="loginpage">
    <div class="main">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="login-form">

    <form class="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(userId, password)">
    <h2 class="text-center forgotpassword">Forgot Password ?</h2> 

    <input type="text" required #password ngModel name="password" required>
     <button type="submit" class="cls-log btn btn-block">change password 
    </button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```